# Cakephp: After log in redirect to the same page

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.0.4. I am facing issues in redirecting after logging in

My application has following pages:
Page x: Apply button.If not logged in go to page Y.
Page Y:  login page

After logging in, how do I redirect the code to page X. 
I think $this->auth->redirect will redirect to page Y and not page X.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the referer into a Session by adding this into the login method:

```
$this->Session->write('redirectUrl', $this->referer());
```

Then after you login then:

```
$this->Auth->redirect($this->Session->read('redirectUrl')); 
$this->Session->delete('redirectUrl'); // Make sure to delete it
```